# Limit the Number of Open Matplotlib Figures in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a small python 3 script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
i = 0;
while(i < 40):
    x = [1,2,3,4,5];
    y = [1,2,3,4,5];
    fig = plt.figure();
    grid = plt.GridSpec(1, 1)
    axis = fig.add_subplot(grid[0,0]);
    axis.bar(x,y);
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    while(len(plt.get_fignums()) > 10):
        pass;
    plt.show(block=False);
    i += 1;
```

My goal is to plot 40 plots. I want the first 10 to plot immediately, and then the next figures will only plot if one of the open 10 plots are closed, one by one. This script seems to almost achieve what I want to do, but it crashes when I try to close one of the first 10 plots. Why does this happen? Thanks

Comment: your thread is blocked in infinite while loop. so your program crashes. you should use close event

Comment: Indeed, the while loop interrupts the (pseudo-)event-loop set up by matplotlib. I suppose what happens then is that once the figure is closed all events that have queued up will want to be processed at once, hence crashing the interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while` loop is not proper idea for this situation, your code should listens for `close event` of figures, then act as desired. these few lines of code may help you:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
desiredNumberOfPlots_initialPopulation=1
desiredNumberOfPlots_total=3

def figOnce():
    x = [1,2,3,4,5];
    y = [1,2,3,4,5];
    fig = plt.figure();
    grid = plt.GridSpec(1, 1)
    axis = fig.add_subplot(grid[0,0]);
    axis.bar(x,y);
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', handle_close)
    plt.show(block=False);
    global desiredNumberOfPlots_total
    desiredNumberOfPlots_total-=1

def handle_close(evt):
    global desiredNumberOfPlots_total
    if desiredNumberOfPlots_total>0:
        figOnce()

i=1
while(i<=desiredNumberOfPlots_initialPopulation):
    print(i)
    i+=1
    figOnce()
```

Comment: This accomplishes what I want it to do, but it seems the figures close immediately as soon as they are opened without waiting for the user to close them. Any idea why?

Comment: I am happy that it helped you. I've tested it and there was no such behavior. have you tried another IDE or something like google colab? just to check everything is fine with your setup

Comment: never mind, it looks like when running from the cmd you just need to put something at then end to make it actually wait for the plots to open. It works if I add an input line at the very end

Comment: I am glad it worked. I tested it in IDLE and didn't know about the cmd problem.